# SQLite database issues when deleting entries

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having some issues working with this SQLite database. Everything worked fine until I added the feature to delete entries. I use a for loop to loop through the entries, but once entries are deleted, not all of the primary keys are between 1 and the number of entries (conditions in my for loop).

This code is part of an activity that displays all of the entries in individual, clickable TableRows. My main issue is how I set my IDs that I use in the OnClickListener.

numFavs is equal to the number of entries in my DB.
favs is an instance of my Database class.

```
    for(long i = 1; i <= numFavs; i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);
        tr.setClickable(true);
        tr.setOnClickListener(this);
        tr.setId((int)i); //NEED TO FIX THIS
        TextView newTV = new TextView(this);
        newTV.setText(favs.getAddress(i).getString("add"));
        tr.addView(newTV);
        ll.addView(tr);     

        TextView spacer = new TextView(this);
        spacer.setHeight(50);
        ll.addView(spacer);
    }
```

It would be ideal to be able to get the ROW_ID (primary key) for each entry and then set the TableRow id to that and also get the Address that pertains to that primary key but..how can I get the primary key of the next entry? Any other method of solving this issue would also be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden text view in your table row. Store your primary key in it and use it the way you want.

Ask me if you face any issues.